# Select a record if not sharing a column value with another record

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a table of the following form,

```
X | Y | Z
_________
1   A   3
1   B   3
1   C   4
1   B   4
```

and I want to query the record which contains B, but only those records that contain B and do not share a common Z field value with a specific record, in this case say A. Thus, ideally the query would return the record "1 B 4".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.y = 'B' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.z = t.z and t2.y = 'A');
```

With indexes on `(z, y)` and `(y)` this is likely to be the fastest method as well.